# product link is white on white background in some pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The product link, vendor's name link and price text is white on a white background on cart popup and cart page.
I tried many different codes on css but could not fix it.
The Text "your order" and "billing details" is also white on checkout page.

```
Billing Details [type="text"] {
    color: Black;
}
.woocommerce-checkout form.checkout label {
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missed something!

you have to set the background with specific color and not generally as `color: black;`

so try `background-color: #000000;`
Also be more specific by defining what's your color planning that you want. Post screenshot or give us a url.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, I want to change the color of the font, from white to black. Here is the link of the photo of my problem. https://www.linkpicture.com/q/IMG_0817.jpg

Comment: EZ dear Giulia! Just give me your live URL and in the next 2 mins. you will get ready the CSS that you need to achieve your goal.